# please help me with this question of probability

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

If A and B are events in a sample space S (with associated probabilities P(A) and P(B)), and
P(A) + P(B) > 1, then if any other event C occurs, either A or B must also occur.

Comment: Please give your question an informative title. Because it's a homework or practice question, please also tag as [tag:self-study] and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Funnily, the "question" does not even include a question, but is merely an assertion. This reminds me of my student time, when we were assigned problems to proof this or that and had to give our solutions to the teaching assistant. Often the problems were only the assertions, but no problem formulation, so one fellow student simply wrote "Yes!" as an answer, which had to be accepted as correct. Not sure, whether you will be equally successful with this approach ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example

$$X=\{1,2,3,4\},$$
$$A=\{x\geq2\},$$
$$B=\{x\geq3\}.$$

Then $P(A)=3/4$, and $P(B)=2/4$, and $P(A)+P(B)=5/4$.